# How to search associations where associated records have a given attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, activerecord, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to search for association records where associated records have a given attribute value. That is, I have a `has_many :through` association like the following

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment_associations
  has_many :comments, through: :comment_associations
end
```

and `comments` have a `title` attribute.

How can I search for `comment_associations` where `comments` have a given `title`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're wanting?

```
# Article model
@article.comment_associations.joins(:comments).merge(Comment.for_title("given title"))

# Comment model
scope :for_title, -> title { where(title: title) }
```

Basically, if you want CommentAssociations then you've got to make the query starting from CommentAssociations... but then you can include and merge in scopes from other, associated models from there.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Where can I find more information about `includes` and `merge`?

Comment: Thanks again. The `order` clause can be merged? I would like even to order `asc` `comment_associations` by title of `comments`. Is it possible through `includes` and `merge`?

Comment: I haven't tried it but maybe `.merge(Comment.for_title("given title").by_title_asc)`, given `by_title_asc` is another scope on the Comment model.

Comment: **BTW**: You should `joins` (not `includes`).